# getElementsByTagName() inside multiple <frame>

Tags: javascript, android, html, asp.net, webview

I know that I can set a input field inside a frame, in this case called "MainFrame", by executing following commands:

```
wv.loadURL("javascript:var mainFrame = document.getElementsByName('mainFrame')[0];"); 
wv.loadURL("var pas = mainFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('Password')[0];");
wv.loadURL("javascript:pas.value = '1';");
```

But how to proceed if there's another frame (MidFrame) inside the "MainFrame" in which I have to set values?

I tried multiple things, a.e.:

```
var mainFrame = document.getElementsByName('mainFrame')[0];
var midFrame= document.getElementsByName('midFrame')[0];
var pas = mainFrame.midFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('Number')[0];
pas.value = '1234'
```

But without any results :/ Can someone explain this to me?

Edit:

Seems to be "MainFrame" inside a "MainFrame"?
[The raw code from the website:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHxdg.png)

Comment: Have you tried `mainFrame.getElementsByName('midFrame')[0]`?

Comment: Yes, but this returns nothing :/